# Typeorm many-to-many with pivot in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I use Laravel as a main backend app and I want to connect to that app's database. I chose Typeorm for Node.js, using Javascript in it with babel compiler.

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relation between User and Challenge entities via pivot table.

User:

```js
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm'
import User from '../models/User'

export default new EntitySchema({
  name: 'User',
  target: User,
  tableName: 'users',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'varchar',
      nullable: false,
      unique: true
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
      nullable: false
    }
  }
}, {
  relations: {
    challenges: {
      name: 'challenges',
      target: 'Challenge',
      type: 'many-to-many',
      joinTable: {
        name: 'users_challenges',
        joinColumn: {
          name: 'user_id'
        }
      },
      cascade: true
    }
  }
})
```

Challenge:

```js
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm'
import Challenge from '../models/Challenge'

export default new EntitySchema({
  target: Challenge,
  name: 'Challenge',
  tableName: 'challenges',
  columns: {
    id: {
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true
    },
    title: {
      type: 'varchar',
      nullable: false
    },
    description: {
      type: 'text',
      nullable: false
    }
  }
}, {
  relations: {
    users: {
      target: 'User',
      type: 'many-to-many',
      joinTable: {
        name: 'users_challenges',
        joinColumn: {
          name: 'challenge_id'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Pivot table has following columns:

```
id
user_id
challenge_id
```

With all these above I'm trying to query data from the users table:

```js
const userRepository = (await db()).getRepository(User)
const profile = await userRepository
  .findOne({ id: req.body.userId }, {
    relations: ['challenges']
  })

console.log(profile)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: Relation "challenges" was not found, please check if it is correct and really exist in your entity.
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: Have you looked at the xample provided by typeorm in the docs? here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md Also this line is vital in the docs JoinTable() is required for ManyToMany relations. You must put JoinTable on one (owning) side of relation.

Comment: I have joinTable object in both User and Challenge entities, I can't pass boolean value to joinTable, because I need to specify the pivot table, it already exists in database.

Comment: My only advice is to make your relation work by following first exactly what the docs say than try to cutomize. If that doesn't work than create aminimal reproduction and push it on github so others can help more.

Comment: Although documentation states that the relationship must be owned by one side, and it does walk you through how it's accomplished using Decorators, there is no documentation on what the equivalent is when using EntitySchemas.

Maybe I am missing something, but I am having a similar problem with a many-to-many relationship when querying from the non-owner side of the relationship without using Decorators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent debugging this with a buddy of mine and went through source code and example code to figure out the right way to this with a "bidirectional" relationship using `EntitySchema`.

According to the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations) the relationship **must** be owned by one side, and one side only regardless if it's a bidirectional relationship (meaning you will be accessing the the relationship from either side).  When a relationship is "owned" by one side as [itwolfpower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419336/itwolfpower) mentioned in the comments above.  This just means that you may only have a single `joinTable` configuration per relationship.

In your example: Let's assume `User` owns the relationship.  This would be equivalent to having the entire `joinTable` configuration object on the `User` `EntitySchema` object:

```
...
  relations: {
    challenges: {
      name: 'challenges',
      target: 'Challenge',
      type: 'many-to-many',
      joinTable: {
        name: 'users_challenges',
        joinColumn: {
          name: 'user_id'
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
          name: 'challenge_id'
        },
      },
      inverseSide: 'User', <--- This needs to match the `target` of the users relation in the Challenge EntitySchema
      cascade: true
    }
  }
...
```

TLDR; added the inverseJoinColumn key to the `joinTable` configuration, and added `inverseSide` to the `challenges` object.

In order to access the `users` relation from your `Challenge` `EntitySchema`, you would set the configuration to the following at a minimum:

```
...
  relations: {
    users: {
      type: 'many-to-many',
      inverseSide: 'challenges',
      target: 'User' <--- This needs to match the `inverseSide` of the challenges relation in the User EntitySchema
    }
  }
...
```

This allows you to run queries from both sides of the relationship:

From the users side:

```
const userChallenges = await userRepository.findOne(1, { relations: ['challenges'] }
```

From the challenges side:

```
const challengeUsers = await challengeRepository.findOne(1, { relations: ['users'] }
```